# VS2010: View .settings file during debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, settings

A Windows Forms application I'm writing in C# is modifying user settings in a .settings file during execution. How can I view the contents of the .settings file during Debug so I can see what the settings values are being changed to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a watch on `Properties.Settings.Default`?